# Running Pktgen with Lua scripts

Tags: lua

I am currently working with pktgen in order to achieve high-rate packet generation for a project. I am using version 2.9.5 of pktgen, along with DPDK version 2.1.0. It does work perfectly fine ( I am able to generate and send packet at 10 Gb/s rate ) until I try to use lua scripts for formatting packets.

As a matter of fact, scripts examples that you can find with the sources seem to not always have the expected behaviour. Simplest scripts work perfectly fine ( HelloWorld.lua for example, I am also able to set packet size, rate or burst with script commands )

```
   package.path = package.path ..";?.lua;test/?.lua;app/?.lua;"
  2 
  3 pktgen.set("all", "count", 0);
  4 pktgen.set("all", "rate", 50);
  5 pktgen.set("all", "size", 256);
  6 pktgen.set("all", "burst", 128);
  7 pktgen.start(0)
```

( the code above does work )

However, I have encountered issues as I tried to define directly a packet format with a table, like in this example :

```
-- Lua uses '--' as comment to end of line read the
  2 -- manual for more comment options.
  3 local seq_table = {                     -- entries can be in any order
  4     ["eth_dst_addr"] = "0011:4455:6677",
  5     ["eth_src_addr"] = "0011:1234:5678",
  6     ["ip_dst_addr"] = "10.12.0.1",
  7     ["ip_src_addr"] = "10.12.0.1/16",   -- the 16 is the size of the mask va    lue
  8     ["sport"] = 9,                      -- Standard port numbers
  9     ["dport"] = 10,                     -- Standard port numbers
 10     ["ethType"] = "ipv4",       -- ipv4|ipv6|vlan
 11     ["ipProto"] = "udp",        -- udp|tcp|icmp
 12     ["vlanid"] = 1,                     -- 1 - 4095
 13     ["pktSize"] = 128           -- 64 - 1518
 14   };
 15 -- seqTable( seq#, portlist, table );
 16 pktgen.seqTable(0, "all", seq_table );
 17 pktgen.set("all", "seqCnt", 1);
```

When I try this script, Pktgen will usually give me a
    Unknown Ethertype 0x0000
Error as soon as I try start 0 in commandline ( 0 is the port I use to transmit packet ). 
 Same problem occurs when I try the main.lua script.

Long story short, I have troubles understanding how the pktgen.seqtable function works, and why it does not work properly in my case. I did not find any really helpful documentation on the net on this subject.

the command I use to launch scripts is :

```
sudo -E $PKTGEN_CMD/pktgen -c 0x7 -n 4 -- -m "1.0,2.1" -f test/set_seq.lua
```

( test/set_seq.lua being a script example ).

Comment: It's been a long time since I last touched DPDK, but... have you tried `pktgen.set("all", "seqCnt", 0)` instead of 1?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same script running with small modification to enable `vlan` in packet generation. Please refer the changes below

```
 local seq_table = {                     -- entries can be in any order
     ["eth_dst_addr"] = "0011:4455:6677",
     ["eth_src_addr"] = "0011:1234:5678",
     ["ip_dst_addr"] = "10.12.0.1",
     ["ip_src_addr"] = "10.12.0.1/16",   -- the 16 is the size of the mask va    lue
     ["sport"] = 9,                      -- Standard port numbers
     ["dport"] = 10,                     -- Standard port numbers
     ["ethType"] = "ipv4",       -- ipv4|ipv6|vlan
     ["ipProto"] = "udp",        -- udp|tcp|icmp
     ["vlanid"] = 1100,                     -- 1 - 4095
     ["pktSize"] = 128           -- 64 - 1518
   };
 -- seqTable( seq#, portlist, table );
 pktgen.seqTable(0, "all", seq_table );
 pktgen.vlan("all", "enable");
 pktgen.set("all", "seqCnt", 1);
```

Executing the modified script does not produce `Pktgen will usually give me a Unknown Ethertype 0x0000 Error as soon as I try start 0 in commandline ( 0 is the port I use to transmit packet ).`

[image]

note: there is mention of a fix to range and vlan id in [pktgen doc](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pktgen-dpdk/downloads/pdf/latest/) page 75 `3.0.01- Fixed the Range sequence and VLAN problem`. hence I recommend to use latest pktgen (I have tested this on PKTGEN 21.11.0)